# Declare pointer as class member C++

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-c++

I'm trying to write a C++ class with a couple of pointers to ints as private members. 
I get this exception when trying to assign a value to the pointer address:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000B140A in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation      writing location 0x00000000.
```

Here is the minimum amount of code that will reproduce the problem on my machine

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class Chunker {
  public:
    Chunker(int cx, int cy);

  private:
    int chunkSizeX, chunkSizeY;
    int *yOff, *xOff;
  };

Chunker::Chunker(int cx, int cy){
  chunkSizeX = cx;
  chunkSizeY = cy;
  *xOff = 0;
  *yOff = 0;
}; 

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
  Chunker chunker(12, 12);
  return 0;
}
```

I just can't figure out what is wrong here?

Comment: You have a good answer below, but why are you using pointers here in the first place ?

Comment: pointers are because in the full code there is a function which on each call will return the next 'chunk' of an array. The xOff and yOff pointers will point to the ints which are keeping track of where it is in the array.

Comment: So xOff and yOff are indexers for some array? You could just define them as ints and use them as `myXArray[xOffset]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare memory somewhere for your pointers

```
Chunker::Chunker(int cx, int cy)
  :  chunkSizeX{cx}, 
     chunkSizeY{cy}
{
    xOff = new int(0);
    yOff = new int(0);
}
```

Otherwise you are assigning a value to a pointer that does not yet have an address.

Obviously if your class is the one that allocates the memory, you need to clean it up too

```
Chunker::~Chunker()
{
    delete xOff;
    delete yOff;
}
```

If your class is the one allocating memory, you also might want to consider having the members be

```
std::unique_ptr<int> xOff;
std::unique_ptr<int> yOff;
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to @Cuber's reply is to replace `*xOff = 0;` by `xOff = nullptr;` (without the `*`). But why pointers?

```
Chunker::Chunker(int cx, int cy)
  :  chunkSizeX{cx}, 
     chunkSizeY{cy}
{
    xOff = nullptr;
    yOff = nullptr;
}

...

Chunker::~Chunker()
{
    delete xOff;
    delete yOff;
}
```